# Rdr Missing on Yosemite

Tags: macos, firewall

I'm trying to add a rule to my computer which was working on my work computer. strangely enough there's no rdr program on my Yosemite. should I install a particular package to obtain it?

```
sh-3.2# rdr pass on lo0 inet proto tcp from any to any port 80 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8080
sh: rdr: command not found
sh-3.2# which rdr
sh-3.2# wtf
sh: wtf: command not found
sh-3.2# uname -a
Darwin sathias-iMac.local 14.0.0 Darwin Kernel Version 14.0.0: Fri Sep 19 00:26:44 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2782.1.97~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Comment: `rdr` is not part of OS X. I see two directions this question could take: "How can I accomplish this with an out-of-the-box installation" or "How can I install `rdr`", can you edit your question to indicate which way you want to go?

Comment: I can assure you that on my work computer rdr was there without installing anything. but that's a new iMac that wasn't updated

Comment: Shouldn't these rules be part of `/etc/pf.conf` then (see http://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/index.html)?

Comment: yes, that's how I made it on my other comp, adding pf.anchors

Comment: In the screenshot above, you seem to be running `rdr` directly in the shell. This will not work.

Comment: Maybe work computer has a OS X Server installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rdr` is part of the packet filter/firewall in OS X and used to configure redirections. You can't run this command directly in the shell but need to edit it into `/etc/pf.conf` and friends. More details are available via `man pf.conf` and in the [PF FAQ](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/index.html).

Comment: So, how comes that my command works.on the other pc?

Comment: OS X as well? Run `type rdr` in the shell to see how the command is defined there.

Comment: ouch, my brain is not working correctly :) I'm at the office and  I can confirm that on this computer there's a pf.anchors and that the rdr command is not working on its own. I shouldn't work on Sunday